# Speech Synthesis API offline languages

Tags: text-to-speech, offline, speech-synthesis

Is it possible to use the speech synthesis API offline? If so, can I use multiple languages or just the default language? 
I have tried this code and it works online, but it does not work offline. How can I make it work online?

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Index</title>
    </head>

<p id = "1"></p>


 <script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>         


<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
        document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
          var audio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
            if (e.keyCode ===49 || e.keyCode ===97) {  //1 is pressed                
            mySpeech();
          }              
        });
      })
     function mySpeech(){
      var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
      msg.voiceURI = 'native';
      msg.lang = 'it-IT'
      //msg.voice = voices[$('#voices').val()];
      msg.rate = 1; // 0 to 1 
      msg.pitch = 1; // 0 to 2
      msg.text = "hello world";    
      speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
    }   

    </script>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only languages that will work offline are the browser's local voices.